# How can I line up different UITableViewCell images and labels?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

All I'm doing in my `cellForRowAt` is setting UITableViewCell's (no subclass) imageView?.image and textLabel?.text values (and fonts and colors). Setting an image via SF Symbols and text according to my model. To go into more detail, there are only three possible cell kinds: a workspace, the "Add Workspace" button, and the archive.

In the following screenshot, I've demonstrated with green lines how these views don't quite line up in a logical fashion. Text is misaligned between all three types of cells, and (annoyingly) the SF Symbols image for that boxy icon with an "add" (+) indicator is slightly wider than the standard image.

Can anyone help me with an easy fix for this that I'm simply just missing? I've already tried setting the imageViews' aspect ratios to 1:1 with constraints. That didn't affect anything.

[image: Text and images are not quite aligned in this UITableView.]

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "workspace", for: indexPath)
        if indexPath.row == addWorkspaceRow {
            cell.imageView?.image = .addWorkspace
            cell.imageView?.tintColor = cell.tintColor
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Add Workspace"
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = cell.tintColor
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        } else {
            let workspace = model.workspaces[indexPath.row]
            cell.imageView?.image = .workspace
            cell.imageView?.tintColor = .label
            cell.textLabel?.text = workspace.displayName
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = .label
            cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        }
    } else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "archive", for: indexPath)
        cell.imageView?.image = .archive
        cell.imageView?.tintColor = .archive
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Archive"
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = .label
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    }

    cell.textLabel?.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: buddy, you just have to play with constraints. Set the constraints of the "add" image same as the default (black) image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I meet the same things, and want to solve it without using custom cell. But it is hard to config the constraint without subclass it.

Eventually, I turn to use custom cell, it is simple to use, and in case you may need to add more stuff in your tableView cell, custom cell is the better place to go.

[image]

### My code, yeah I'm making a music player now;)

```
class LibraryTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    var cellImageView = UIImageView()
    var cellLabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: "libraryTableCell")
        
        cellImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cellImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        cellImageView.tintColor = .systemPink
        contentView.addSubview(cellImageView)
        
        cellLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cellLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        contentView.addSubview(cellLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cellImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
            cellImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            cellImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            cellImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44),
            
            cellLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
            cellLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 10),
            
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

```
class LibraryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var tableView = UITableView()
    let cellTitles = ["Playlists", "Artists", "Albums", "Songs", "Genres"]
    let imageNames = ["music.note.list", "music.mic", "square.stack", "music.note", "guitars"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white
        title = "Library"
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(LibraryTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "libraryTableCell")
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.rowHeight = 48
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.6)
        ])
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellTitles.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "libraryTableCell", for: indexPath) as? LibraryTableCell else {
            fatalError("Unable to dequeue libraryTableCell")
        }
        
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        
        let imageName = imageNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.cellImageView.image = UIImage(systemName: imageName)
        
        let title = cellTitles[indexPath.row]
        cell.cellLabel.text = title
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 20, bottom: 8, right: 8)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `contentMode` property of `UIImageView` will do the trick:

```
cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

It's happening because the images themselves are not the correct dimensions.

Comment: I actually tried this and it doesn't change anything. Even setting horizontal hugging priority for the imageView to high didn't work.

Comment: It does seem you're using the native imageView of UITableViewCell, have you tried subclassing it and implementing your own imageView and fixating its size using constraints ?

Comment: I'm certain that would work. I was just avoiding that (admittedly tiny amount of) work if possible. It feels like it should be possible with the base class.

Comment: Honestly, I always go straight into subclassing UITableViewCell, just for the added customization in case I'll ever need it.

Answer (score 0):

Your image in tableviewCell is wrong contentMode. It is reason due to wrong layout of your label.

You have option to fix that problem:

**Option1**:

open file XIB tableviewCell and change content mode of UIImage

**Option 2**:

you can set by code:
`yourUImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`

Comment: You seem to have skipped over some comments on the other (same) answer. This doesn't work with the native UITableViewCell class. It only works when you've subclassed for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I searched a long time for solution for the problem you're describing, but sadly I haven't found any. The problem seems to be the native `UIImageView` in the `UITableViewCell`. There are essentially two workarounds:

**A)** Resize all images you use as table view cell icons to a certain width (e.g. 30 and height 44). Draw this space and center the icon (while keeping the original size)

**B)** Get used to Apple's "You can use our pre-built solution but if you want to change it even a tiny bit you have to re-build everything from the bottom up"-philosophy and just use custom cells for everything you do in the app. With a custom cell, you could simply set the imageView width to a certain value.

I wonder how they solved that problem in the iOS Mail app.